# Configuring Xbindkeys bindings for Logitech M510 mouse

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, key-binding, logitech-mouse, xbindkeys

On Windows 7 my mouse buttons are configured with Logitech SetPoint software. 
But today I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi. Of course my extra buttons are not working now on Ubuntu. I installed xbindkeys and xbindkeys-config but couldn't figured out how to bind my buttons. I started `xev` from the terminal and checked if the buttons are recognised, they are. So, what I'm doing:

1. Start `xbindkeys-config`
2. Press `New` button
3. My first side button (Forward on the browsers by default) is `button 9` as I checked with `xev`, so for `Key` I write `b:9`.
4. On Windows I'm using it for opening a new tab in the browser. So, for `Action` I write `ctrl+t`, `control+t` or `Control + t | m:0x4 + c:28` which is the combination when click `Get Key` button and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

But it's not working. If I write `xterm` instead, it's working, so my button `b:9` is recognised properly. The problem is the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. How to write it?

**The bindings that I want to save are:**

Left Scroll Button (b:6): **Volume-**

Right Scroll Button (b:7): **Volume+**

Back Button (b:8): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for closing the current tab

Forward Button (b:9): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for opening a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of researching I finally figured it out. 
For using key combinations I installed xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

After that I used these actions:

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: `xdotool key ctrl+t`

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: `xdotool key ctrl+w`

etc.

And for volume up and down I used these actions:

```
amixer sset Master  1+ unmute
```

and

```
amixer sset Master  1- unmute
```